# Linux iptables DNAT 53306 to 127.0.0.1 3306

Tags: iptables, mysql5.5, dnat

mysql real port is 3306。

I want public network using 53306 to visit mysql,and 3306 not allowed access from public network.

How to write the iptables rules DNAT 53306 to 127.0.0.1 3306 ? help me

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the Traffic from Port 53306 to 3306 with

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 53306 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3306
```

Comment: but，3306 must be open，I want 3306 deny access from public network!